# How to convert dbf to csv in python 3.6.9?

Tags: python, csv, type-conversion, dbf, pdb-files

I have large amount of .dbf data (around 1gb each) and I need to convert it to .csv in order to use in my actuarial tool. I've found a code which works with python 2 (my friend tried and managed to produce dummy.csv). I have to use 3.6.9 (workplace uses 3.6.9) but can't make it run in that version.

I'm very new at python so any help is much appreciated. thank you very much !

```
import csv 
from dbfpy import dbf 
import os
import sys

filename = 'DUMMY.dbf'
if filename.endswith('.dbf'):
  print ("Converting %s to csv" % filename)
  csv_fn = filename[:-4]+ ".csv"
  with open(csv_fn,'wb') as csvfile:
        in_db = dbf.Dbf(filename)
        out_csv = csv.writer(csvfile)
            names = []
        for field in in_db.header.fields:
             names.append(field.name)
        out_csv.writerow(names)
        for rec in in_db:
            out_csv.writerow(rec.fieldData)
        in_db.close()
        print ("Done...")
else:
  print ("Filename does not end with .dbf")
```

of course, sorry, forgot the error.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/env_python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-4-11540611f260>", line 2, in <module>
    from dbfpy import dbf

  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/env_python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dbfpy/dbf.py", line 280
    print repr(_rec)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you provide the error

Comment: sure! I just added it.

Comment: It looks like you cannot import `dbfpy` package.

Comment: well I saw that dbfpy package was installed. do you think I call it wrong?

Comment: I think it is about `dbfpy` package. I'll go into package to see what's wrong. You can try another package like dbfread: <https://pypi.org/project/dbfread/>

Comment: As an aside, I see you calling `in_db.close()`. Could that be handled by a context manager, just like the file object?

Comment: I'll check that dbfpy package first. and try dbfread.

Comment: also I'll try that Alexander. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `dbfpy` is Python2.7<sup>1</sup> only, and you are running it in Python 3+.

You could try using my [`dbf`](https://pypi.org/project/dbf/)<sup>2</sup> library, which would look something like:

```
import dbf
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.exit('must provide name of dbf file to convert')
elif if sys.argv[1][-4:].lower() != '.dbf'):
    sys.exit('%r does not appear to be a dbf file' % (sys.argv[1], ))

dbf_file = sys.argv[1]
dbf_table = dbf.Table(dbf_file)

# create .csv file in same location as .dbf file
dbf.export(dbf_table)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> At least, the version of `dbfpy` you have installed is either 2.7 only, or has some 2.7-only code still embedded in it.

<sup>2</sup> My `dbf` library is 2/3 compatible.  It does not, however, support index files.

Comment: why i show module 'dbf' has no attribute 'Table?

Comment: @ManManYu: I would guess you have some other dbf module installed.  Try `print(dbf.__file__` and see what comes up.